# selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not sure why I get this error. Could someone please help.

UPDATE: I fixed it.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\GitHub\BlooketHack\main.py", line 43, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("var div=(\"<div/><style>[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]{visibility:hidden;display:none;}[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[4],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[6]{visibility:visible;display:block;}</style>').appendTo(\"body\");");
  File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected identifier
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.128)
```

Code-In-Question:

```
driver.execute_script("var div=(\"<div/><style>[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]{visibility:hidden;display:none;}[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[4],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[6]{visibility:visible;display:block;}</style>').appendTo(\"body\");")
```

A little more readable:

```
driver.execute_script("var div=(\"<div/><style> \
            [@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3] { \
                visibility:hidden; \
                display:none; \
            }[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[4],[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[6] { \
                visibility:visible; \
                display:block; \
            }</style>'\").appendTo(\"body\");")
```

Basically all I'm trying to do is inject a website with updated CSS. If there are any other options for this I'm open for improvement too.

UPDATE: I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why there is a semicolon at the end? It shouldn't be there in Python I guess

Another thing... It is more understandable when you put single quotes in double quotes instead of \"

Comment: "simple quotes" ... I think you mean "single quotes".

Comment: You're right ! (I am french so my english is not perfect) Thanks

Comment: I think your English is VERY good... I just assumed you mistyped or something. :)

Answer (score -1):

It was just a mistype I guess. I'm not sure how I fixed it to be honest.